# matrix inequality upper bound $\|A(B+C) +D(B-C)\|/2$?

Tags: matrices, inequality, normed-spaces, matrix-equations

Suppose $A,B,C,D$ are matrices with operator norm at most 1. Then is it true that
$\|A(B+C) +D(B-C)\|/2$ is at most $1$ (where $\|\cdot \|$ is the operator norm of a matrix, where by operator norm, I mean largest eigenvalue of the matrix)? I have tried many examples and it seems true, but I am not able to prove something in general.

Comment: The largest eigenvalue of the matrix is not a norm.

Comment: The induced two norm of a matrix $M$ (also the largest singular value) is the square root of the largest eigenvalue of $M^TM$. Perhaps this is the source of your confusion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A=I$, $B=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$,
$C=D=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$. All of these have an induced two norm
of one.

Then $A(B+C)+D(B-C) = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 2 & 0  \end{bmatrix}$ which has an induced norm of $2 \sqrt{2} > 2$.

```
octave:1> A = [ 1 0 ; 0 1 ] ;
octave:2> B = [ 1 0 ; 0 -1 ] ;
octave:3> C = D = [ 0 -1 ; 1 0] ;
octave:4> 
octave:4> norm(A)
ans =  1
octave:5> norm(B)
ans =  1
octave:6> norm(C)
ans =  1
octave:7> norm(D)
ans =  1
octave:8> 
octave:8> S = A*(B+C)+D*(B-C)
S =

   2   0
   2   0

octave:9> norm(S)
ans =  2.8284
octave:10> 
octave:10> sqrt(eig(S'*S))
ans =

   0.00000
   2.82843
```

Comment: I am sorry but why is the spectral norm of the final matrix $2\sqrt{2}$ isn't it just 2 (the eigen values are $\{2,0\}$)?

Comment: Just compute the norm explicitly, it is not difficult. Try applying the matrix to the vector $(1,0)^T$.

Comment: Exactly my point, if you try with the vector $(1,0)^T$, the eigenvalue is $2$ and it is a rank 1 matrix, so this is the only non-zero eigen value!

Comment: What have the eigenvalues got to do with it? Just compute the induced two norm. If you apply the matrix to the vector $(1,0)^T$ you will get the vector $(2,2)^T$ which has norm $2 \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: The norm is not a function of the eigenvalues of the matrix.

Comment: Ok, when I meant operator norm in the question, I meant largest singular value of these matrices are bounded by $1$. In your counterexample that isn't the case. Does that make sense?

Comment: It is simple to create a $2 \times 2$ matrix with zero eigenvalues and non zero norm.

Comment: Peace! Ok, let me write out my math. :) So, it is clear that there is only one-non zero eigen value right, since it  $M=A(B+C)+D(B-C)$ is rank-1. The eigenvalues of the matrix $[1 0; 1 0]$ are just $\{0,1\}$. Forget your induced norm stuff (sorry for this language), but just the largest eigenvalue is $2$. *not* $2\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Do you know the definition of induced norm?

Comment: Just $\max_v||Av||_2/||v||_2$

Comment: Ok, wikipedia says induced matrix norm is the spectral norm which is also defined as $\sqrt{\lambda_{\max}(A^TA)}$. In this case $A^TA=[2 0; 0 0]$, so $\lambda_{\max}(A^TA)=2$ and the induced norm is $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: I think you are trolling me. What do you get when you compute $(A(B+C)+D(B-C)) (1,0)^T$? This is a lower bound on the norm of $A(B+C)+D(B-C)$. The norm is $2 \sqrt{2}$.  I have no idea where the 20 comes from in your previous comment, you need to check your computations.

Comment: Just for giggle I have added the Octave computation which may help persuade you.